# Android Studio can't find library classes after Gradle build

Tags: android, dependencies, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to add a `.jar` library to my project into the `/libs` folder. Here is my `grade.build`:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android'

    dependencies {
        compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar', 'libs/java-api-wrapper-1.2.0-all.jar')
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 17
        buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 16
        }
    }
```

After I add that, I build my project and there are no errors. But when I try to use the class in my code `private ApiWrapper wrapper`, I get an error:

```
Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class ApiWrapper
```

I can't quite find where the error is. Is my `grade.build` not ok, or am I supposed to build it some other way?

Comment: Do you have any sub-projects, or just one main gradle project?  I was getting a similar error in one of my sub-projects...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using the command line, in the root of your project, run :
`./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build`

Then recompile your project in studio and you should see your new lib.

Comment: I thought if you run Build -> Rebuild Project it will run assembleDebug task for Gradle, which runs 'clean' task beforehand anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much. This command line solution helped. I was tired finding solutions for my problem. But finally this worked

Answer (score 18):

Set **minifyEnabled to false for all your library projects** in build.gradle.
See accepted answer by Scott Barta in this thread.

[See accepted answer by Scott Barta in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117884/android-studio-app-with-library-project-fails-to-build)

Comment: You have saved my day!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 16):

> Goto File ⇒ Invalidate Caches & Restart

Solved my problem

Comment: best answer, tnx

Answer (score 10):

- As first option, i think will be enough `Syncronizing the Project with Gradle Files`.

[image]

- Another option, from the command line, run the batch file `gradlew.bat` located inside your project folder:

[image]

```
./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build
```

Comment: The first option worked for me, but the second one not.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar situation where Android Studio couldn't find a library that definitely existed.  Even though I was able to compile my project in Android Studio, run it from Android Studio in the emulator or on a physical device, and build it from the command line using gradlew, the Android Studio IDE complained `Cannot resolve symbol 'ConstraintLayout'`.  I believe I had imported the library correctly because I followed Google's instructions: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project.

Anyway, I ended up solving the problem as follows:

1. Close Android Studio
2. Delete the .idea folder in the project's directory
3. Open Android Studio
4. Re-import the project so Android Studio can regenerate the .idea folder

This in-fact solved the problem.  I believe Android Studio somehow corrupted the .idea folder when I had done "Android Studio" > "Check for Updates" earlier in the day.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Android studio File and press Invalidate Caches/Restart. This worked for me to find the library