# Android - Gradle: Copy to native-libs

Tags: android, gradle

I am very new to the Android / Gradle build environment, and google helpt me a lot, but for this I have tried a lot of things, but can't seem to get it to work!!

When I try to load the Vitamio Library (its saved as .jar file inside /app/libs/vitamio/, everything goes well, there are no Gradle build error.. But when I start the app, it gives the error that 'vinit.so' cannot be found.. The solution is copying it manually to the static-libs....

**See problem** -> [Vitamio Sample Error - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load vinit findLibrary returned null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289930/vitamio-sample-error-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-load-vinit-findl)

Now my folder structure is as following:

[image]

**ATTEMPT 1**
[Android Studio, Gradle, OpenCV and NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921862/android-studio-gradle-opencv-and-ndk/20926595#20926595)

> Error:(69, 0) Could not find property 'jniLibs' on task ':app:packageDebug'.

When I try with jniFolders, nothing happens.

I placed it inside a lot of folders, just to try.. But it doesn't make any difference...

**UPDATE 1**

I think the copying worked, I had to install NDK and add it to local.properties file, but now it gives the following error:

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
>   A problem occurred starting process 'command '/android/ndk/ndk-build'

Without any errors.. Any help in find a debug.log somehwere, because the error says nothing about whats going wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Gradle lets you handle dependencies a lot easier than using JARs! Open the app build.gradle file (there are two, open the first one in your screenshot that you posted) and add this line:

```
compile 'me.neavo:vitamio:4.2.2'
```

in the dependencies section.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick reply.. I also tried that, but it results in the same problem that vinit is not copied over to native-libs..

Comment: Try removing the library first and then re-building the app