# Android / Java rookie.. How to debug following error

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android / Java developing, and google helpt me until so far, so good..

But now I try to load Vitamio, what is not very easy to be honest.. After a lot of pain with Gradle, .so file-includes and NDK.. I am stuck with the following error.

> :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareMeNeavoVitamio422Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDexDebug
>   :app:dexDebug
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lio/vov/vitamio/BuildConfig;
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>       at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

The error gets triggered over here->

> com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lio/vov/vitamio/BuildConfig

Google tels me there has to be some duplicate dependency.. But I cannot find the 'duplicate'...

Any tips?

Thanks!

P.S I use Android studio

**Update**
StackOverflow does not like it when I post a gradle file... So I took a screenshot.

[image]

**Update 2**

All over google people mention that .jar files has to be removed.. But there are no .jar files in my project anymore (at least as far I know).

[image]

**Update 3**

This is my manifest-merger-debug-report

```
INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0 reason: use-sdk injection requested
>MERGED from me.neavo:vitamio:4.2.2:2:5
>MERGED from com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0:20:5
    android:targetSdkVersion
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
    android:minSdkVersion
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
```

Comment: show us your gradle files

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103288/multiple-dex-files-define-my-package-buildconfig-cant-find-the-cause and in general: [This google search query](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+Multiple+dex+files+define+Lio%2Fvov%2Fvitamio%2FBuildConfig&oq=android+Multiple+dex+files+define+Lio%2Fvov%2Fvitamio%2FBuildConfig&aqs=chrome..69i57.1465j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Thanks for the tips.. I tried it with dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }.. But then I get the error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lio/vov/vitamio/BuildConfig";

Comment: what is the package name within your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: @PeterP, package="com.example.afterparty.app"

Comment: do you have any libs in your lib folder?

Comment: I only have the armeabi dirs.. That hold the .so files.. To fix the previous error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150022/android-gradle-copy-to-native-libs/31150076?noredirect=1#comment50310501_31150076

Comment: Just by looking at everything you posted, please make sure you are using the latest Android plugin which is `1.2.3`. Why compile with Java6?

Comment: Hi @JaredBurrows..Thanks! I updated the build.gradle to 1.2.3 and removed the compileOptions, but problem stays... I'm stuck with it for 2 days already.. Think I will just start from scratch once again...