# Android Studio can't find Android Support Library classes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-studio-2.2

I was using Android SDK 25, but due to a bug with SDK 24 and above, I've reverted back to SDK 23. I was also using support library v25 too. I needed to revert back to support library v23.x as otherwise Gradle gave an error telling that support library major version can't be higher than the SDK version.

I've tried many different versions from [Android Support Library Revision History](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) in Gradle, but now, when I try to build my project, Android Studio can't find any of the library classes:

[image]

The error list goes on for anything from support library.

I've tried the answer to [Android Studio can't find library classes after Gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882844/android-studio-cant-find-library-classes-after-gradle-build) and I've also tried invalidating caches and restarting, but no avail, still the same. In Gradle sync, I'm not getting any errors at all.

Here is the entry in my gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
```

All I've done is reverting back to SDK v23. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: recyclerview has its own dependency.

Comment: pls update your full gradle file

Comment: @Blackbelt it was working before the downgrade with the same gradle file?

Comment: hardly to say why. For RecyclerView you need `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'`, in your case

Comment: @Blackbelt you are right. interestingly, I've also had to change the version number of appcompat library to 23.1.1 and added recyclerview as you said (though 23.1.1, it didn't work with lower version). I have no idea why it was working without it before. anyway, it solved my problem, could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RecyclerView` needs a separate dependency. Add

```
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
```

to your `build.gradle` if you want to use it

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have downloaded the v23 dependencies in the SDK manager.

Open the SDK manager with the button on top in Android Studio, find the SDK you are using and check the boxes if they are not checked.