# library is not getting imported

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have used this library earlier also but dont know why today i am not able to get this library properly `com.jaredrummler.android.colorpicker` [image: when i call]
[image: gradel]
this is the gradle file and i have tried to rebuild and clear project i tried to invalidate cache also but nothing happened but earlier it was working all my library are update also what should i do now.

Comment: stupid suggestion, but it worked once for me, delete this library from Gradle, sync, then paste it and sync again

Comment: @LieForBananas i tried to make a new app imported all library but that also didnt work

Comment: Well, it was worth a try, have you tried any of the suggestions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882844/android-studio-cant-find-library-classes-after-gradle-build)?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the project-cache-dir, i.e., `.gradle`(*or if you can find the relevant artifacts in cache*) folder where all the libraries are cached, and sync again; it should resolve the dependency.

If still facing issues, it is worth verifying that you have not mentioned 2 different versions of same dependencies in different .gradle scripts.
It also results in this issue due to ambiguity compiler gets confused which artifact to use.

Comment: bro but that will  not happen when i create a new project na but let me try that too